# How can I convert the locations of a group of objects into the vertices of an object?

Tags: animation-nodes

I have a bunch of locations from a group of objects and I want to turn it into the vertices of a new objects with no edge connections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

In the .gif I invoke the Pie Menu with the W key.

[image]

The important part in this setup is the small loop that takes a list of objects and returns their locations in a new list. This basic setup is pretty common all kinds of animation nodes trees.

**Extra notes:**

The python equivalent to this loop would be:

```
# Long Version
locations = []
for object in objectList:
    location = object.location
    locations.append(location)

# More Pythonic Version
locations = [object.location for object in objectList]
```

The core of the addon translates for your node tree into python code that looks like this:

```
 def main(loop_iterator_0):
     global _frame_9pg, _enabled_jfa
     loop_generator_output_0 = []
     loop_zipped_list = list(zip(loop_iterator_0))
     loop_iterations = len(loop_zipped_list)
     for current_loop_index, (loop_iterator_element_0, ) in enumerate(loop_zipped_list): 
         # Node: 'NodeTree' - 'Object Transforms Input'
         try:
             _location_9pg = loop_iterator_element_0.location
         except:
             _location_9pg = mathutils.Vector((0, 0, 0))
             _rotation_9pg = mathutils.Euler((0, 0, 0))
             _scale_9pg = mathutils.Vector((0, 0, 0))
             _quaternion_9pg = mathutils.Quaternion((1, 0, 0, 0))
         if _enabled_jfa:
             loop_generator_output_0.append(_location_9pg)
         pass
     return loop_generator_output_0
```

Answer (score 3):

Not too familiar with animation nodes, but you can do this with a short python script:

```
import bpy

groupName = 'Group'              ## <== change group name if needed
g = bpy.data.groups[groupName]  

locations = [ o.location for o in g.objects ]

name = 'MeshFromGroup'
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new( name = name )

o = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
o.location = (0,0,0) # place at object origin
bpy.context.scene.objects.link( o )

mesh.from_pydata( locations, [], [] )
```

Just copy this into a new textfile in the text editor, change the name of the group if it's not "Group", and press the "Run Script" button.